# How to access the variables in a nested class with array object?

Tags: java, class, nested

So I have an object array and i am trying to access the variables in a nested class. I get a null pointer exception. newbie here so the way i am approaching this problem may be wrong.

```
foo Foo = new foo();
Foo.initcfoo(1);
Foo.cfoo[0].a = 1;


public class foo {
   childfoo[] cfoo;

   public void initcfoo(size){
      cfoo = new childfoo [size];
   }
   public class childfoo{
      public int a,b,c;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initialized the array but not its members. Change to

```
   public void initcfoo(size){
       cfoo = new childfoo [size];
       for (int i = 0; i < cfoo.length; i++) {
           cfoo[i] = new childfoo();
       }
   }
```

Consider using Java naming conventions. Start class names with an uppercase letter. Use `camelCase` for variable and method names.

---

When you don't do this, the statement

```
Foo.cfoo[0].a = 1;
```

is trying to access the element at index 0 but that element has not been initialized and is therefore `null`. Trying to dereference `null` in order to access the field `a` throws a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

This line `cfoo = new childfoo [size];` just initialises the array (meaning the array is of size `size` which will hold any instance of object `childfoo`), but still the array is empty and it does'nt have any contents in it.

But before populating the array with instances of `childfoo` you are accessing it `Foo.cfoo[0].a` which results in `Null Pointer Exception` means `Foo.cfoo[0]` is `null`.

The solution would be to first populate the array with the object of `childfoo` and then access it.

e.g

`cfoo[0] = new childfoo()` then
`cfoo[0].a`

you can learn more about [java array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

please respect the naming conventions in java, and also try to not to access the variables of a class directly (except from inside the class itself or one of it's inner classes)

use setters and getters, like :

```
public class Foo {

    // private variables
    private ChildFoo[] cFoo;

    // setter
    public void setCFoo(Foo.ChildFoo[] cFoo) {
        this.cFoo = cFoo;
    }

    // getter
    public Foo.ChildFoo[] getCFoo() {
        return cFoo;
    }

    public void initCFoo(int size) {
        cFoo = new ChildFoo[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < cFoo.length; i++) {
            cFoo[i] = new ChildFoo();
        }
    }


    public class ChildFoo {

        // private variables
        private int a, b, c;

        // setter
        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        // getter
        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setB(int b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        public int getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public void setC(int c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public int getC() {
            return c;
        }
    }
}


    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.initcFoo(1);
    foo.getCFoo()[0].setA(1);
```